# delete image from folder PHP

Tags: php

I have a folder where I keep my images, named `img/`. I have a table with all of my images:

```
<table border="3">
    <tr>
        <td>    
            <?php
            $files = glob("img/*");
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                echo "<div class='divimages'>"; 
                echo '<img src="'.$file.'"/>';
                echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete image'/><br>";
                echo "</div>";  
            }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

How can I delete the image associated to the button with the value:`"Delete image"`.

Comment: using mcryans answer below you will have to get the button to post a form with the filename(s) in the post data then loop through the list of file names and use the unlink function in php.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There are a few routes. One, the most simple, would involve making that into a form; when it submits you react to POST data and delete the image using `unlink`

**DISCLAIMER**: This is not secure. An attacker could use this code to delete **any** file on your server. You must expand on this demonstration code to add some measure of security, *otherwise you can expect bad things*.

Each image's display markup would contain a form something like this:

```
echo '<form method="post">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$file.'" name="delete_file" />';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete image" />';
echo '</form>';
```

...and at at the top of that same PHP file:

```
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
  $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
  }
}
// existing code continues below...
```

You can elaborate on this by using javascript: instead of submitting the form, you could send an AJAX request. The server-side code would look rather similar to this.

**Documentation and Related Reading**

- `unlink` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php
- `$_POST` - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
- `file_exists` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php
- `array_key_exists` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
- *"Using PHP With HTML Forms"* - http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Comment: No problem! Take care to add some security provisions there, otherwise it could end in tears :P. Some ideas for security, depending on how you're using it: .htaccess password requirement; checking that the `$filename` is in the image folder before deleting it; session-based user login; or PHP-based password protection.

Answer (score 33):

You can delete files in PHP using the [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function.

```
unlink('path/to/file.jpg');
```

Comment: Your link is broken

Answer (score 5):

First Check that is image exists? if yes then simply Call unlink(your file path) function to remove you file otherwise show message to the user.

```
              if (file_exists($filePath)) 
               {
                 unlink($filePath);
                  echo "File Successfully Delete."; 
              }
              else
              {
               echo "File does not exists"; 
              }
```

Answer (score 3):

For deleting use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php
Hope you'll can to write logic?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code. This is Simple PHP Image Deleting code from the server.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="photoname"> // You can type your image name here...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$photoname = $_POST['photoname'];
if (!unlink($photoname))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $photoname");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted $photoname");
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    require 'database.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $image = "SELECT * FROM slider WHERE id = '$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $image);
    $after = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    if ($after['image'] != 'default.png') {
        unlink('../slider/'.$after['image']);
    }

    $delete = "DELETE FROM slider WHERE id = $id";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $delete);

    if ($query) {
        header('location: slider.php');
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path = 'img/imageName.jpg';
if (is_file($path)) {
    unlink($path);
} else {
    die('your image not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to delete all `.png` files starting from current directory, I've created a small script. It iterates over all available folders (one level only), searches for all `.png` file and deletes them:

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');

foreach ($dirs as $directory) {
    $images = glob($directory . "/*.png");

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo "DELETING: " . $image . "<br>";
        unlink($image);
    }
}
```

if the script is located in app folder (`app/index.php`) it will search (one level) in all `app/{folderName}` for `.png` files and delete them. You can change the `.png` to `.jpg` or what you need.