# delete image from file server in php

Tags: php, image, file

I have row that contains (id, name, pic), I can delete this row from the database, but cannot delete the image from the file server.

Below code should delete the image file:

```
if(isset($_GET["delete"])){

$pi=$_GET["delete"];
$qry="delete from item where id=".$_GET["delete"];
$de = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);

$filetmp = $_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"];
// $filename = $_FILES["pic"]["name"];
$qr ="SELECT id FROM item where id='$pi'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$qr);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$id = $row["id"];
}
$path = "uploads/$id.jpg";
//move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$path);
$fpath = "images_upload/Uitem/$path";
unlink($fpath); // delete file

}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but worth a read:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Enable displaying of PHP errors and try again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: your mysqli statements are wrong...

Comment: Ciuld you please check, whether this is possibly permission related (e.g. your webserver user is allowed to delete the file)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete image from folder PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005899/delete-image-from-folder-php)

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to use the path on your server to delete the image, not the image url. 
Like

```
unlink('/var/www/test/'.$fpath);
```