# PHP Codeigniter- How to delete an image from folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been working with my codeigniter project for gallery part.

I've succeed on displaying all images, now I want to make function to delete images from folder. I tried it but get some error.

My Controllers

```
function delete_img(){
    if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
      $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
      if (file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
        echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
      } else {
        echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
      }
    }
}
```

My Full Views, Gallery Part

```
<?php
    //FOLDER GALLERY-PART
     $dirname = "./assets/images/gallery/";
     $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

     array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $images), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $images);

     foreach($images as $image) {

    "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 portfolio-item logos'>
       <div class='portfolio-wrapper'>
         <div class='portfolio-single'>
           <div class='portfolio-thumb'>
             <img src='.$image.' class='img-responsive' alt=''>
               </div>
                <div class='portfolio-view'>
                   <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
                     <li><a href='gallerydetail'><i class='fa fa-link'></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href='.$image.' data-lightbox='example-set'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='portfolio-info'>
                    <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='" . base_url() . "gallery/delete' method='post'>
                        <input type = 'hidden' name='delete_file' value='.$image.' />
                        <input type = 'submit' value='Delete' class='btn btn-common'/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
            }
        ?>
```

I get this code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005899/delete-image-from-folder-php) I tried to implement this into codeigniter, the result was error. Like this:

```
Could not delete ../assets/images/gallery/hermesed231486375164.jpg., file does not exist
```

The file was exist, but idk why it errors.

EDITED:
Ok I was trying to fixed it with base_url, the result:

```
Could not delete http://k-art.local/../assets/images/gallery/hermesed231486375164.jpg., file does not exist
```

Now, how to delete this thing [../] it might worked when it disappear

Comment: Are you working in live or in localhost?

Comment: try to print `$filename` and make sure that this file is really exists in your directory, I see a point after the file extension `hermesed231486375164.jpg*.*`, from where this point came?

Comment: There's some mistakes over there ../assets/images/gallery/blabla.jpg

How to make it work with base_url?

Comment: check $filename value using print_r($filename); what it returns

Comment: @Mohammad that name come from my username session + date('U') at upload part. It's the name of the image that I want to delete

Comment: @HermesDjohar try to delete the image without checking if its exist or not, and share us the result

Comment: @Mohammad ../assets/images/gallery/hermesed231486375164.jpg. No such file or directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED WITH IDIOT WAY

From this:

```
<input type = 'text' name='delete_file' value='.$image.' />
```

To this.. Just deleting the dot[.] mark. Really? LMAO

```
<input type = 'text' name='delete_file' value='$image' />
```

But anyway thanks for replying :)

Comment: as I told you early, pay attention to the point :-P, next time try to share your whole "related to the issue" code

Answer (score 0):

Change permission folder gallery for 0777

OR Try:

```
function delete_img(){
    if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
      $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
      if (file_exists($filename)) {
        chmod($filename, 0777);
        if(unlink($filename)) {
            echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';    
        }else echo 'Could not delete '.$filename;
      }else echo 'File does not exist: '.$filename;
    }
}
```